# mysql - subselect with order by not working

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

I have two tables like these

| id | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

and

| id | parent_id | version_1 | version_2 | status | payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2 | 1 | 1 | ordered | 8 |
| 101 | 2 | 2 | 1 | changed | 14 |
| 102 | 2 | 3 | 1 | paid | 9 |
| 103 | 2 | 1 | 2 | ordered | 22 |
| 104 | 2 | 2 | 2 | changed | 13 |
| 105 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ordered | 4 |

And what I want is this result table

| id | Product | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 4 |
| 2 | B | 22 |

The logic:

1. status ordered first, then changed, then paid
2. Max version_2
3. Max version_1
   My sequel is

```sql
select t1.*
, t2.status
, t2.payment

from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id and t2.id = (select t2.id from t2 
                                                  order by field(t2.status, 'ordered', 'changed', 'paid')
                                                           t2.version_2 desc
                                                           t2.version_1 desc
                                                  limit 1)
```

Could someone tell me why it doesn't work although the subsequel only works.

Comment: Please add table data like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) instead of snaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
select t1.*, t2.status, t2.payment
from t1
left join t2 
    on t1.id = t2.parent_id 
    and t2.id = (
        select t2.id 
        from t2 
        order by 
            field(t2.status, 'ordered', 'changed', 'paid'),
            t2.version_2 desc,
            t2.version_1 desc
        limit 1
    )
```

As I understand your question, you would need to *correlate* the subquery; the condition on `parent_id` should go inside the subquery. I would also recommend properly aliasing the different tables to avoid ambiguity:

```
select t1.*, t2.status, t2.payment
from mytable1 t1
left join mytable2 t2 
    on t2.id = (
        select t20.id 
        from mytablet2 t20
        where t20.parent_id = t1.id
        order by 
            field(t20.status, 'ordered', 'changed', 'paid'),
            t20.version_2 desc,
            t20.version_1 desc
        limit 1
    )
```

Note that recent versions of MySQL support lateral joins, which make the query simpler to express and more efficient:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from mytable1 t1
left join lateral (
    select t20.status, t20.payment
    from mytablet2 t20
    where t20.parent_id = t1.id
    order by 
        field(t20.status, 'ordered', 'changed', 'paid'),
        t20.version_2 desc,
        t20.version_1 desc
    limit 1
) t2 on 1
```

Finally, you could also use window functions:

```
select t1.*, t2.status, t2.payment
from mytable1 t1
left join (
    select t20.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by parent_id 
            order by 
                field(t2.status, 'ordered', 'changed', 'paid'),
                t2.version_2 desc,
                t2.version_1 desc
        ) rn
    from mytable2 t20
) t2 on t1.id = t2.parent_id and t2.rn = 1
```